# Powershell to Update Google Sheets

Tags: powershell, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform

I have imported a module **UMN-Google** from https://github.com/umn-microsoft-automation/UMN-Google in PowerShell which is used to create, update Google Sheets.

1. I create a Project in https://console.cloud.google.com/
2. Enabled the Google Sheets and Drive API.
3. Create a Service Account and generated a private key(P12 format).

Following is the PowerShell Code to generate Access Token and same access token is used to create or update the sheet which is working perfectly.

```
Import-Module UMN-Google

# Set security protocol to TLS 1.2 to avoid TLS errors
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

# Google API Authozation
$scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file"
$certPath = "C:\Temp\sheets-script-336006-5db4e6b09111.p12"
$iss = 'sheets-script@sheets-script-336006.iam.gserviceaccount.com'
$certPswd = 'notasecret'
try {
    $accessToken = Get-GOAuthTokenService -scope $scope -certPath $certPath -certPswd $certPswd -iss $iss
} catch {
    $err = $_.Exception
    $err | Select-Object -Property *
    "Response: "
    $err.Response
}

$accessToken

# Create new spreadsheet
$Title = 'Patching Spreadsheet'
$SpreadsheetID = (New-GSheetSpreadSheet -accessToken $accessToken -title $Title).spreadsheetId
$SpreadsheetID

# Create new sheet
$Sheet = 'Computers'
Add-GSheetSheet -accessToken $accessToken -sheetName $Sheet -spreadSheetID $SpreadsheetID
```

Now I have many google sheets to which I want the script to be integrated in-order to update the data in various sheets. We have disabled drive sharing outside domain due to which I am unable to give permission to service account for sheets editing.

Is there any way or possibility which can be done so that the service account has the permission to update the sheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is related to something that I have run into recently, specifically with having a service account "impersonate" a user within our Google Workspace in order to perform calls to Google Drive API.

Our solution came from this guide here: [Delegating domain-wide authority to the service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority).

The idea is to have your service account assume the role of an account in your Google Workspace that does have the permissions you need, in this case to edit specific Sheets. The instructions are pretty straightforward in that guide; just a quick setup in the Admin console.

It's worth noting that we are not using `Get-GOAuthTokenService` to get an access token. We are building a JWT using [Svyatoslav Pidgorny's JWT module here](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/JWT/1.9.1) and using it to get an access token via [the https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token endpoint](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#authorizingrequests).

I only took a quick peek [at UMN-Google's implementation](https://github.com/umn-microsoft-automation/UMN-Google/blob/master/UMN-Google.psm1), but I see that their JWT-creation doesn't offer any `sub` parameter in the JWT payload. This is the parameter that let's you designate which Workspace user that you want the service account to impersonate.

Comment: Hi Petracles, Is there a way I can add the sub parameter by modifying the UMN-Google.psm1 file?

Comment: Hey @John, you should be fine to edit anything in UMN-Google. The last commit to the project was July 2020. I think paramater-izing `sub` should be straightforward.

Comment: I edited the UMN-Google.psm1 and added `[Parameter(Mandatory)]
[string]$sub` after line 121 and `sub = $sub` after line 154. Then forced import the module and ran the script by passing `$sub`. I get the following error

`Status         : ProtocolError
Response       : System.Net.HttpWebResponse
Message        : The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.`